# Using vector drawables, how would I scale an image depending on the size of the viewport

Tags: java, android, xml, vector-graphics, android-vectordrawable

Before, I did this by just having the different versions of the images within their respective res/drawable folder.
thanks

i want to fill the available space while retaining the scale. i want the image to be able to fill 92x92.. or 144x144.. and so on depending on what the phone needs visually.. 
I've tried different combination(min/max height/width)s but nothing is giving me any consistency

Comment: What do you mean by no consistency, what problems are you having?

Comment: keeping the image to-scale, it always looks stretched

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your scaleType. If you use scaleType fitXY it will stretch the image, maybe try fitCenter. Check here for some examples of scaleTypes http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/4709/imageview/18024/set-scale-type#t=201610141547015800495

Comment: android:scaleType="fitCenter" did the trick